# GRPC Server throws exception when using SSLServerCredentials in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, grpc

So im currently trying to set up a grpc server with ssl enabled but i always get the exception "Failed to bind port "0.0.0.0:8888"
The port is definitely not in use.
If it is important in server.crt the CN is localhost.
It also works perfectly fine with `ServerCredentials.Insecure`

**UPDATE:**
I got the server working, i had an issue with the certificate, however now now the client can't connect and i get an RpcException with `StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Empty update"`

```
var cacert = File.ReadAllText($"{path}/ca.crt");
        var servercert = File.ReadAllText($"{path}/server.crt");
        var serverkey = File.ReadAllText($"{path}/server.key");
        var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(servercert, serverkey);
        var sslCredentials = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair> { keypair }, cacert, true);

        var server = new Server
        {
            Services = { Comm.BindService(new Communicator()) },
            Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", 8888, sslCredentials) }
        };
        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server started");
        Console.ReadKey();

        server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
```

Answer (score 2):

It was a certificate issue.
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet
in this repo is an example with certificates in case anyone else is struggling

Comment: Hi Felix, I'm having this same issue. What was your cert issue and how did you fix it? Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: i made a mistake creating the ssl key myself
tbh i just wanted to try out the ssl authentication so i just used the certificates in the grpc-dotnet repo

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. So you used their cert on the client. What about the server? How did you do that?

Comment: Do you have a code example, like a super simple one?  I'm stuck on this as well

Comment: sorry im afraid not
but i used the keys from this repository https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/testassets/Certs/InteropTests